# Angular - custom popup html

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, binding, click

I'm trying to achieve something in which I have to open a popup on button click, there can be multiple buttons with their own overlay popups and they should close when clicking outside the popups. Right now I'm using **TemplateRef (#toggleButton in my case)** to open them but it's working on only one button only i.e, the first one and it opens all the popups at the same time. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm attaching stackblitz link, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8tnwg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**HTML:**

```
<ng-container>
            <tr>
                <td class="custom-td" style="overflow:visible;">
                    <button #toggleButton class="icon-info" (click)="showTooltip()"></button>
                    <div #menu class="overlay-text" [ngClass]="status ? 'open' : ''">
                        <p>This is a placeholder text and will be copied
                            if you click on button!</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text">
                            <button  class="icon-filecopy"></button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="custom-td" style="overflow:visible;">
                    <button #toggleButton class="icon-info" (click)="showTooltip()"></button>
                    <div #menu class="overlay-text" style="background-color: yellow" [ngClass]="status ? 'open' : ''">
                        <p>This is a placeholder text and will be copied
                            if you click on button!</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text">
                            <button  class="icon-filecopy"></button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="custom-td" style="overflow:visible;">
                    <button #toggleButton class="icon-info" (click)="showTooltip()"></button>
                    <div #menu class="overlay-text" style="background-color: red" [ngClass]="status ? 'open' : ''">
                        <p>This is a placeholder text and will be copied
                            if you click on button!</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text">
                            <button class="icon-filecopy"></button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
```

**TS:**

```
status: boolean = false;
  @ViewChild("toggleButton") toggleButton: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  @ViewChild("menu") menu: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.renderer.listen("window", "click", (e: Event) => {
      console.log("click outside");
      if (
        e.target !== this.toggleButton.nativeElement &&
        e.target !== this.menu.nativeElement
      ) {
        this.status = false;
      }
    });
  }

  showTooltip() {
    this.status = !this.status;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, to begin with, I wouldn't add anything on the constructor, you should move all that to ngOnInit https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit.
Then, If you want each button to open a different pop up, you need to make them unique, if you use the same flag to enable/disable for all, it will affect all. 
If you don't want to create separate methods, send an ID, and toggle only the affected... I hope it makes sense

Comment: @rmjoia How do I open with unique ids? Sorry I'm asking dumb question, relatively new here

Comment: There are no "dumb questions" questioning is healthy and the first step to learn is admitting you don't know :) I posted an answer with a possible solution, I hope it helps you get the hang of it and get there.. eventually you might want to check this FREE awesome resource. https://thinkster.io/topics/fundamentals-of-angular

Comment: I added on the second StackBlitz closing when clicking outside, may need a bit of tuning though.. but I can't spend more time on this, I think that both examples provide solid information on how to achieve what you're looking for, from what I understand

Answer (score 0):

Only the first button works because your ids are not unique, workaround would be using: `@ViewChild(Button) toggleButton: QueryList<ElementRef>`
but as rmjoia commented - proper way to achieve what you want is to make unique ids and unique tooltip toggle per button

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is the following, I'm not saying this one is the best, or the only, in programming, there are usually more than one solutions and each with their trade offs.

I made the function toggle, but if you want, you can make one set to true, and the button on the popup set to false... sky is not even the limit ;)

[StackBlitz example forked from yours](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4j5pt)

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  isTooltip1Visible = false;
  isTooltip2Visible = false;
  isTooltip3Visible = false;

  constructor() {}

  toggleTooltip(tooltipId) {
    switch (tooltipId) {
      case 1:
        this.isTooltip1Visible = !this.isTooltip1Visible;
        break;
      case 2:
        this.isTooltip2Visible = !this.isTooltip2Visible;
        break;
      case 3:
        this.isTooltip3Visible = !this.isTooltip3Visible;
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Invalid tooltip Id");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

***app.component.html***

```
<table appClickOutside (clickOutside)="closeDropdown()">
    <tbody>
        <ng-container>
            <tr>
                <td class="custom-td" style="overflow:visible;">
                    <button #toggleButton class="icon-info" (click)="toggleTooltip(1)"></button>
                    <div #menu class="overlay-text" [ngClass]="isTooltip1Visible ? 'open' : ''">
                        <p>This is a placeholder text and will be copied
                            if you click on button!</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text">
                            <button (click)="toggleTooltip(1)" class="icon-filecopy"></button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="custom-td" style="overflow:visible;">
                    <button #toggleButton class="icon-info" (click)="toggleTooltip(2)"></button>
                    <div #menu class="overlay-text" style="background-color: yellow"
                        [ngClass]="isTooltip2Visible ? 'open' : ''">
                        <p>This is a placeholder text and will be copied
                            if you click on button!</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text">
                            <button (click)="toggleTooltip(2)" class="icon-filecopy"></button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="custom-td" style="overflow:visible;">
                    <button #toggleButton class="icon-info" (click)="toggleTooltip(3)"></button>
                    <div #menu class="overlay-text" style="background-color: red"
                        [ngClass]="isTooltip3Visible ? 'open' : ''">
                        <p>This is a placeholder text and will be copied
                            if you click on button!</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text">
                            <button (click)="toggleTooltip(3)" class="icon-filecopy"></button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to keep this dynamic, there can be number of buttons and popups

Comment: even if you make it dynamic, the example should be good enough to get you there. 
If you have a list of items, and then the buttons and pop ups are dynamically populated, you can use a `isVisible` property on the item, and toggle it using the item ID.   
Based on the code you provided, this is a possible solution...

Comment: I created another Stakblitz just to show... how it can be done dynamically https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-be9sr1
Your question was about how to do it for that static code, and I think my answer is valid, if you're looking for something like this on this example, you can see the similarities and how you could use my answer to get to this outcome, or, edit your question and I'll replace the code if this is what you're looking for